# How to write 1 tuple as sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A 2-tuple is $(a, b) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$
What about a 1 tuple? Is it $(a) = \{\{a\}\}$?
Then if $a = b$: $(a, b) = (a, a) = \{\{a\}, \{a, a\}\} = \{\{a\}, \{a\}\} = \{\{a\}\}$
So $(a, a) = (a)$?

Comment: In the future, please typeset your question with mathjax and add more details about the context behind your question and what you've tried.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The definition you are using for an ordered pair is called a [Kuratowski pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski%27s_definition).

$$ (a, b)_K = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\} $$

Unfortunately, it does not immediately generalize beyond 2 elements.

For example, $\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, b, c\}\}$ is *not* a viable definition of an ordered triple because it cannot distinguish $(a, a, b)$ and $(a, b, b)$. This doesn't directly address the *singleton* case, but it does show that the Kuratowski pair is not a construction for encoding *tuples* as sets.

One thing you can do if you want to represent tuples of arbitrary length is to represent them as partial functions* with domain $\mathbb{N}$, for example.

$$ (a,) = \{(1, a)_K\} \\
(a, b) = \{(1, a)_K, (2, b)_K \} \\
(a, b, c) = \{(1, a)_K, (2, b)_K, (3, c)_K\} \\
\textit{and so on} $$

---

Note that in this definition, we're using the Kuratowski pair construction to build our definition of a 2-tuple $(a, b) = \{(1, a)_K, (2, b)_K\}$ rather than directly using the pair *as* our definition of a 2-tuple.

*Also note that, if we want to define an $n$-ary "function" as a set of $n+1$-tuples where every element of the domain is associated with a unique element of the codomain, then tuples themselves are, strictly speaking, not functions. However, the same intuition from the encoding of a function carries over to the encoding of tuples.

Comment: @M.Logic: It's not an error to say Kuratowski's pairing does not generalize to higher lengths. It doesn't. We can apply it itetatively for finite sequences, true. But that is not a generalization.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Maybe we agree. What I mean is that the definition for $n$ tuples is also based on the definition for ordered pairs in the first definition for $n$ tuples in my post.

Comment: I'm careful to distinguish a "Kuratowski pair" $(a, b)_K$ from a "2-tuple" $(a, b)$, but that is a good point. If you want to be able to encode non-unary functions, then you need to encode a function as a set of tuples and thus tuples themselves would not be functions. (I suppose you could use a Kuratoski pair for unary functions only, but that seems a bit odd.)

Comment: Maybe you did it for the benefit of the OP, but starting to count with $1$ instead of $0$… I agree with everything else.

Comment: I started with $1$ because I call the projections out of a tuple $\pi_1, \pi_2, \cdots$, not $\pi_0, \pi_1, \cdots$. Is it more usual to start with $0$ (and possibly let the projections be "mismatched")?

Answer (score 7):

In set theory, we usually (see page 18 in [Hrbacek, K. and Jech, T., 1999](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824779150) and page 7 in [Jech, T., 2000](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540440852)) define $n$ tuples as follows.

**Definition 1.** Suppose $n$ is a natural number and $x_0,\cdots,x_{n-1}$ are sets. Set

\begin{align*}
(\,)&:=\varnothing,\\
(x_0)&:=x_0,\\
(x_0,x_1)&:=\{\{x_0\},\{x_0,x_1\}\},\\
\vdots\quad\qquad&\qquad\qquad~\vdots\\
(x_0,\cdots,x_{n-2},x_{n-1})&:=((x_0,\cdots,x_{n-2}),x_{n-1}).
\end{align*}

**Remark 2.** As you see, $0$ tuples and $1$ tuples has nothing to do with Kuratowski's definition for ordered pairs$^*$, while $n$ tuples with $n\geq 2$ are based on Kuratowski's definition for ordered pairs. The reason that we set $0$ tuples to be the empty set is clear, and the reason that we set $1$ tuples to be the element laying in itself is to coincide with definitions for unary relations (any subset of $X$ is a unary relation on $X$) and with definitions for unary Cartesian products ($X^1=X$ which selects elements of itself as its elements).

Furthermore, with definitions for $0$ tuples, $1$ tuples and $2$ tuples unchanged, we can also define $n$ tuples with $n\geq 3$ to be functions with domain $n$.

**Definition 3.** Suppose $n$ is a natural number no less than $3$ and $x_0,\cdots,x_{n-1}$ are sets. Set

$$(x_0,\cdots,x_{n-1}):=\{(0,x_0),\cdots,(n-1,x_{n-1})\}.$$

**Remark 4.** Note that $2$ tuples (ordered pairs$^\dagger$) can't be defined as functions with domain $2$, since the definitions for functions depends on relations while the definitions for relations depends on $2$ tuples, and so the definition for $2$ tuples should only be Kuratowski's or similar (for example, Hausdorff's or Wiener's) way.

**Remark 5.** Both of the two definitions for $n$ tuples with $n\geq 3$ have their own advantages: (1) Definition 1 has real order while Definition 3 has imaginary order since the elements of functions have no order and the imaginary order follows from the order of ordinals (natural numbers); (2) Definition 3 is clearly simpler than the first one. In fact, since we also define sequences as functions with ordinals as domains, if we adopt Definition 1, then tuples can only be regarded as finite sequences while in fact not, and if we adopt Definition 3 then $n$ tuples are indeed $n$ sequences (finite sequences).

Anyway, $(a,a)=\{\{a\}\}\neq a=(a)$. Note that by Axiom of Foundation/Regularity, we can by induction show that: if $n$ is a non-zero natural number, then $a\neq \underbrace{\{\cdots\{}_{n\text{ many}}a\underbrace{\}\cdots\}}_{n\text{ many}}$.

---

$*$ By the way, Kuratowski's definition for ordered pairs is great although it seems to be very simple at first glance since it transforms the *order* of elements laying in the ordered pairs into the *difference of sets* (not difference operation of sets) of elements laying in the ordered pairs,  and based on it we can define other basic mathematical concepts such as relations, functions and so on.

$\dagger$ Considering of no mathematical definition, there are many [equivalent names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) to *$2$ tuples*: couple, double, ordered pair, two-ple, twin, dual, duad, dyad, twosome. So it's better to define $2$ tuples and ordered pairs to be the same object, while @Gregory Nisbet 's new definition for $(a,b)$ (i.e., 2 tuples) and definition for $(a,b)_K$ (i.e., Kuratowski's definition for ordered pairs) are different objects. Without this, it's also ok to define $2$ tuples in @Gregory Nisbet 's new way. By the way, in fact @Gregory Nisbet 's new way is the same as Definition 3 for $n$ tuples with $n\geq 3$ as above.

Comment: We do??? I always thought that we define ordered pairs, and then tuples are just functions with the appropriate domain.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Both of the two definitions are ok and have their own advantages: (1) the first one have real order while the second one have imaginary order since the elements of functions have no order and the order for the second one follows from the order of ordinals (natural numbers); (2) the second one is clearly simpler than the first one. In fact, since we also define sequences as functions with an ordinal as domain, if we adopt the first one, then tuples can only be regarded finite sequences while in fact not, and if we adopt the second one then $n$ tuples are indeed $n$ sequence.

Comment: Yes, but what you're saying is that $((((x)))) = (((x))) = ((x)) = (x) = x$, and worse, $(x, y) =((x, y))$. So, is it a pair or a tuple?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, although it seems to be a little strange it will not  bring any problem. For tuples, the essence of them is that they have length and order, while $1$ tuple is just a particular case.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila By the way, for the name, 'ordered pair' is equivalent to '2 tuples' since   we also have 'unordered pair'.

Comment: I find the statement that 2-tuples can't be defined as functions misleading: one defines the ordered pair $(a,b)$ using Kuratowski's definition, and then define an $n$-tuple as a set of ordered pairs containing exactly one pair $(k,x)$ for every $k\in n$. This implies that 2-tuples and ordered pairs are different, but I don't see a problem there. It feels a lot more natural than the idea that 2-tuples somehow can't be defined as functions, while the rest can.

Comment: @Vsotvep The point is that, in modern set theory we define ordered pairs first and then define binary relations as sets of ordered pairs. And if we have ways to define binary relations first or independent of ordered pairs, the words in the post should be rewritten.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila I supplied a reference for the first definition.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila There is another reason why we set $(x)=x$: naturally we set the unary Cartesian product of $X$, i.e., $X^1$ to be $X$, which select elements of itself as its elements.

Comment: So, the notation $X^Y$ for all the functions from $Y$ to $X$ doesn't apply when $Y=1$?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Please be careful that, if we define $n$-ary Cartesian product in this way, then the unary Cartesian product $X^1$ is different from the set of all functions from $1$ to $X$, and so I use $^1\!X$ ($^Y\!X$ more generally, I think you certainly saw this notation before which is also convenient to define the exponentiation of cardinals $\kappa^\lambda$ to be $|^\lambda\kappa|$) to denote the latter set.

Comment: @user953376 Note that $a=\{b\}=\{\{a\}\}$ is false because of Axiom of Foundation, and you can see the conclusion in the post. And also, it will bring no problem to show $a\neq\{\{a\}\}$ by Axiom of Foundation which has nothing to do with the proof of the lemma: if $(a,b)=(c,d)$ then $a=b$ and $c=d$.

Comment: @M.Logic It would however be more satisfying to have definitions that "work" also in $\mathsf{ZF}-$Foundation, say.

Comment: @Hagenvon Eitzen You are right that all the definitions should *cost* as less as possible. By the way, Axiom of Foundation is not necessary for both of the two definitions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila *So, is it a pair or a tuple?* – this definition of *n*-tuples performs ‘type erasure’: in other words, given this definition of tuples, when you get handed a set, you have to know in advance which kind of tuple it is supposed to be in order to meaningfully operate on it (or obtain this information from some other object, a form of ‘RTTI’ if you will).

Comment: @M.Logic although I can understand the argument for $(x_0):=x_0$, I did not understood why $():=\varnothing$. Mainly, we expect that $X^0=\{\}$. But with your definition, $X=\{a,b,c\}$, $X^0=\{(),(),()\}=\{\varnothing,\varnothing,\varnothing\}=\{\varnothing\}≠\{\}$. Shouldn't $():=\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is absolutely nothing, not even an empty set.

Comment: ^ a correction, $X^0=\{()\}$ regardless of what $X$ is. It is still however, $X^0=\{()\}=\{\varnothing\}≠\{\}$.

Comment: @Sourav Kannantha B Note that  in set theory $X^0=\{\varnothing\}=1$ which could be regard as the set of functions from $0$ to $X$, i.e., the empty function, and we usually use no $\{\}$ which is in fact $\varnothing$ too.